# how to remove play images over the html5 video player for iphone web applications

Tags: iphone, web-applications, html5-video, tapestry

I am developing web application for smart phones using tapestry. I have html5 video tag in my player page. In my video player, its shows default play image over the player at the first snapshot.

This is my video code

```
<video id="video" width="100%" height="180px;" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
<source src="${videoUrl}" type="video/mp4" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I want to remove this play images from the player. Please any one say how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify some poster image, e.g. it can be an empty image:

```
<video id="video" width="100%" height="180px;" 
       style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" 
       poster="${posterUrl}">
    <source src="${videoUrl}" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```